# JQUERY change src with click, and another after time

Tags: jquery, click, src

i would change src image attribute with click, and after two seconds return at the first src.

```
$('img.change').click(function(){   
$(this).attr('src','second.png')
.delay(2000).attr('src','first.png');  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/hym6U/

```
$('img.change').click(function () {
    var self = this;
    $(self).attr('src', "http://placekitten.com/100/100");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(self).attr('src', "http://placekitten.com/g/100/100");
    }, 2000)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
    $('img.change').click(function(){   
          $(this).attr('src','second.png');
          setTimeout("changeToOriginal", 2000);
     });

     function changeToOriginal() {
          $("img.change").attr('src','first.png');
     }
```